# searching for a pattern in java

Tags: java

yes guys its a kind of homework...but your help will be appreciated..

sorry for the previous incomplete question..i am a newcomer so please don't mind...

I've a string, e.g., "how aare you a re yo u a r e you ar e" and the string with which I want to compare is "are".

Now the problem is to find the occurrence of "are" in such a way that if it appears as "aare" it is ignored since it becomes a different word altogether, if it appears as "you a re" it is accepted since 'you' will be considered as a different pattern and 'a re' as another, if it appears as " u a r e " it is rejected since it forms a 'specific pattern like space word space word... so u will also become a part of 'are' and hence it should be rejected' and if it appears as "you ar e" it is accepted and "you a r e " is also accepted.

- "aare" it is ignored
- "you a re" it is accepted
- " u a r e " it is rejected
- "you ar e" it is accepted
- "you a r e " is also accepted

i tried the following code:

```
public class testPattern1 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a="How aare yoar u a r e yo ar e";
        String compare="are";


        int i,temp=0;
        for(i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            if (a.charAt(i)==compare.charAt(0))
            {
                temp=i;
                temp++;

                for(int d=temp;d<a.length();)
                {
                    while(a.charAt(temp)==' ')
                    {
                        temp++;
                    }

                    if(a.charAt(temp)==compare.charAt(1))
                    {
                        temp++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    while(a.charAt(temp)==' ')
                    {
                        temp++;
                    }
                    if(a.charAt(temp)==compare.charAt(2))
                    {
                        System.out.println("matched at"+temp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("not matched at"+temp);
                    }

                }

            }


        }

    }

}
```

hope you guys have now understood the question..

Comment: Can you post a list of acceptable and non-acceptable patterns for "are", that will help to figure out what exactly should be done.

Comment: @smit : yes ofcourse..the patterns are as follows: 1.if 'are' appears in 'aare' or any other word such as 'hare' or 'barel' i.e. if it is combined with some other alphabets then it won't count. 2. if it appears in 'the doctor s a r e there' then also it won't count since ' s a r e ' as a whole forms a specific pattern, if it was like ' the doctors a r e there' then it would have been accepted. 3. If it appears as 'hello how ar e you' it is accepted. 4. 'how a re you' is also accepted.

Comment: I must say you have very eccentric patterns of "are". However it is achievable. Your best option is to follow @ null code (Answer 2). Make array of all your acceptable occurrences for "are". Read every line by chars and compare your all occurrences with string. You will have to add some logic hacks to achieve some string patterns. If you got any problems let us know. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line = "How aare yoar u a r e yo ar e";
    String pattern="are";
    String arraySt[]= line.split("\\s+");
    for(String temp :arraySt)
        if(temp.equals(pattern))
            System.out.println("Found");
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the above code doesn't satisfy my requirement. Because if i try to find 'are' in the following string:"how aare you". it finds it. But it should not find 'are' since both(aare & are) are different words.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this is ok for you.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
String line = "how aare you a re yo u a r e you ar e you a r e";

String [] occurence ={" are","a re","ar e","you a r e"};
int total = 0;
for(String occ:occurence){
     int size = (line.split(occ)).length;
     if(line.contains(occ) && !line.startsWith(occ) &&  !line.endsWith(occ)){
         size = size-1;  
     }else if(!line.contains(occ)){
         size = 0; 
     }
        System.out.println(occ+" "+ (size));
        total=total+size ;

}

System.out.println("Total Ocuurence "+total);


}
```